# How to avoid user to add breakpoint to stop the count down timer in js?

Tags: javascript

I've been working on a online test system.User takes test in a limited time. So I use js timer function.

```
 function timer(intDiff){
    window.setInterval(function(){

    var minute=0,
        second=0;       
    if(intDiff > 0){

        minute = Math.floor(intDiff / 60);
        second = Math.floor(intDiff) - (minute * 60);
    }
    if (minute <= 9) minute = '0' + minute;
    if (second <= 9) second = '0' + second;

    $('#minute_show').html('<s></s>'+minute+'minute');
    $('#second_show').html('<s></s>'+second+'second');
    intDiff--;
    }, 1000);
} 

$(function(){
    timer(intDiff);
});
```

but user can add breakpoint in chrome to make the time stop. How do I avoid user to do that.I know I can check the server time and client submit time.Is there any easy and better solution?

Comment: Keep a count server side too. You can't rely on JS too much.

Comment: it's impossible. since the code is on user's computer. They can of course edit it as they want.The only way to avoid this is use serverside code.

Comment: Hey if they figure that out, they deserve a job. Anything on the client is the clients. You need something server side, you can't rely on js at all.

Comment: As has been said, you can not completely avoid your code stopped since your code is entirely on the computer of the person who runs, but you can make his task more difficult by using such a Web Worker or a Shared Web Worker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer, you can't.

Long answer:

You're design is bad, you should base your time measurement using the date object. Each time a loop will get triggered, check the current date with `new Date()` and keep track of the last date.

Keep in mind that even if you set an interval of 1000ms, it doesn't mean that on the function will get called every seconds. It only means that it will never get called before 1000ms. As Javascript runs in one thread, any blocking process may delay calling methods that will remain in the event queue (`setInterval` in this case).

This way, it might not be necessary to track server time this way.